# Writing to .out file

Tags: c, file, integer, printf

Is it possible to write integers to a ".out" file? I'm thinking something like below, but when I try it, the pointer just ends up as null.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    int arrInt[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    FILE* writeFile;
    writeFile = fopen("outFile.out", "w");
    for(int k = 0; k < 5; k++) {
        fprintf(writeFile, "%d", arrInt[k];
    }
    if(writeFile == NULL) {
        printf("File is NULL");
        exit(-1);
    }
    fclose(writeFile);
    return 0;
}
```

output:

```
File is NULL
```

If it's not possible, what would be a viable alternative? Thanks

EDIT: I already had all added suggestions, but added them here just to be clearer. I do want them to be a single line with no spaces or new lines, it's actually a much more complex problem, but I simplified it a lot just to understand this one piece.

Comment: If the pointer is null, you're getting an error when trying to open the file. Use `perror()` to print the error message.

Comment: How could it not be possible? Millions of programs write integers to files, what do you think makes yours different?

Comment: side note: don't forget to use `fclose` at the end

Comment: `printf("File is NULL, reason: %s\n", strerror(errno));` You could try an absolute pathname that you know is 'owned' by you.

Comment: fprintf(writeFile...  close parens is missing.

Comment: Note that you should test that `writeFile` is non-null before you use it in the `fprintf()` loop.

Comment: This kind of error is often caused by running the program in a not writable directory, or if the output file is already opened in another program on Windows. `perror` or `strerror(errno)` should give relevant informations.

Comment: How are you running your program?  Are you clicking a "Run" button in an IDE, or are you using a command-line compiler, and running your compiled program at the command line?

Comment: *I already had all added suggestions* Please, please, please show output of `perror` or `strerror`.  If you didn't know already, learn it now: Rule 1: *Always* check return value of file-handling functions like `fopen`.  Rule 2: When they fail, *always* print (a) the name of the file your were trying to operate on and (b) the `strerror` (or `perror`) text.  These two rules are fantastically important but fantastically easy for beginners to overlook.  But you will never read or write data to/from files until you are able to apply these rules consistently.

Comment: Please copy/paste the *exact* code that refuses to open the file. Not "something like my code".

Comment: The error was actually related to using getopt(), as I had incorrect syntax but I fixed it and it now works as expected. Thank you for your help